# bindingRedirect is not working with Visual Studio 2012 Test Projects?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have just created an ASP.NET MVC 4 app with a Visual Studio 2012 Test applicaton. Then I have add some bindingRedirect like,

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="*****" publicKeyToken="*****"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="*.*.*.*-*.*.*.*" newVersion="*.*.*.*"/>
      </dependentAssembly>          
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Tested the same in console application works but not work when I run Visual Stdio 2012 Test Project.

May be it's a bug as stated in this [thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1865767.aspx).

Comment: In what `.config` did you place it?

Comment: @leppie, it's App.config. BTW, same App.config's appsettings are working.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but did you have any luck with this problem? I'm facing it right now. Also, do you have VS 2012 Update 1 installed?

Comment: @anderson.pimentel it's a bug. I have'nt abl to resolve

Comment: @user960567 Oh, crap...  No luck with VS 2012 Update 1 either? I was about to install it here to see if it could help.

Comment: @anderson.pimentel, I have't checked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It seems to be patch with VS2012 Update 3 (the update 2 still has the bug)